# Trouble Accessing Selenium Grid on Google Cloud Run from Remote Client

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, google-cloud-platform

I'm experiencing issues with accessing my Selenium Grid, which is hosted on Google Cloud Run, from a remote client. The Grid works perfectly when I run it locally using Docker, but I encounter problems when trying to access it on the cloud.

Environment:

Selenium Grid Version: 4.10.0
Cloud Service: Google Cloud Run
Client Environment: MacOS, Python, selenium, docker image: seleniarm/standalone-chromium

Python code:

```py
    try:
        options = ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--headless')

        SELENIUM_SERVER_URL = ""

        driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor=SELENIUM_SERVER_URL,
            options=options
        )
        print(driver)
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(1)
        driver.get("http://www.python.org")
        elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
        print("driver bere", driver.title)
        print("elem: ", elem)
        driver.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        print("error found", e)
```

I thought it was originally an issue about cloud run not having the incorrect port. I exposed the image to 4444.

I get the error below when running my python code.

```
Message: Unable to execute request for an existing session: java.io.IOException: HTTP/1.1 header parser received no bytes
2023-12-29T21:39:27.118703876Z Stacktrace:
```

What I Tried:

Verified that the Selenium Grid is operational on Google Cloud Run.
Checked network accessibility and ensured no firewalls are blocking the connection.
Ensured the Selenium client version is compatible with the Selenium Grid version.
Ran the grid locally using Docker, where it works as expected.

How can I successfully connect to the Selenium Grid on Google Cloud Run from a remote client? Are there specific network or configuration settings on Google Cloud Run that I need to adjust to make this work?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
The SELENIUM_SERVER_URL is an autogenerated google cloud run url.